# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error on PHP Site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a folder called `src`. Inside this folder, there is an `.htaccess` file rewriting all requests to `index.php` if a file hasn't been found:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This is used for a REST-like API. However, I also have a folder `frontend` in the `src` folder, which is, well, like the name says, a frontend.

The site works without problems, but still, the Apache log says:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

What could be the problem here?

**EDIT**
When I set `LogLevel debug` I get the following message

```
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3116): [client 178.200.171.1] r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] core.c(3122): [client 178.200.171.1] redirected from r->uri = /js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [debug] mod_deflate.c(700): [client 178.200.171.1] Zlib: Compressed 634 to 390 : URL /var/www/projectname/htdocs/src/index.php, referer: http://projectname.com/home.php
[Wed Feb 25 17:58:15 2015] [error] [client 178.200.171.1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit
```

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: You said `The site works without problems`. Are you sure that is a current error message? Is the time stamp current? It's not going to work but then give you an error message at the same time.

Comment: Hi, yes, I'm using the `tail -f logfile` command to get theall  message.

Comment: Well, then do what it says and turn on the debug to get more details of the cause.

Comment: It's not mine server, so I'm not allowed to do that, sorry. I could ask the server provider though.

Comment: Yes something is wrong if apache is giving errors even if the site seems to function correctly. I would ask your host.

Comment: Calling him right now. Will comment again, when I got more information

Comment: Hi, was set up. Edited my initial post

Comment: Do you have any other rule in this .htaccess or any other .htaccess in your filesystem?

Comment: Hi. Nope, the only other rule is just a password protection

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use the `src` folder, maybe try adding the `RewriteBase` to the htaccess rules inside the `src` folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /src/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /src/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, but unfortunetely it didn't help. The problem still exist.